# Multiple google cloud project linking to API access in play console

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-play-console

We have multiple apps uploaded in a single developer account that are featuring in app subscription. All the apps uploaded on play console have corresponding google cloud project having pub sub setup. I am able to link only one google cloud project at a time.
[image: screenshot to relate]

Now I want to link all those Google Cloud Projects to API Access in Play Console, but there is no option to add multiple projects to it.

Comment: did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same confusion after reading

> This should not be the same Google Cloud project used for API calls in your apps

But since you can connect only one Google Cloud project to one Play Console account, there's no choice but to create a dedicated project on Google Cloud just to link to your Play Console account.

Create the new Project through Play Console, then make a service account for that project. You can use this service account to access androidpublisher api.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what いちにち said in his answer, but I would like to add more clarification for this.

I was also confused with this statement:

> This should not be the same Google Cloud project used for API calls in
> your apps

I found this more detailed explanation below, and with it, it is much more clear what is the meaning of the previous statement. They only "recommend" creating new dedicated Google Cloud Project which will be connected to Play Console (Google Play Developer Account) and used only for Play Console. But creating dedicated project for this makes sense, because it will be used in Play Console for all other projects.

> Before you can access the Google Play
> Developer API, you must link your Google Play Developer Account to a
> Google Cloud Project. In most cases, we recommend that you create a
> new Google Cloud Project dedicated to your Google Play Developer
> Account, but you can link an existing project. Keep in mind that each
> Google Play Developer Account can only be linked to a single Google
> Cloud Project. If you have multiple apps in the same Google Play
> Developer Account, they all must share the same Google Cloud Project.

Source: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is if you want to get data from your own Google Play Developer account, it is not related to the projects you created for your apps.